# Razor syntax in JavaScript code block

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to know if it is a good practice to use razor in JavaScript code. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var variable = @some.Id
</script>
```

Or it's better to create hidden value and then take it with JavaScript, like this?

```
<input type="hidden" id="someId" value"@some.Id" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   var variable = $('#someId').val();
</script>
```

EDIT:

```
@{
var formVariables = serializer.Serialize(new
                                             {
                                                 id = Model.Id, 
                                                 name = Model.Name, 
                                                 age = Model.Age
                                             });

<input type="hidden" id="header_variables" value="@formVariables"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "/Scipts/..."></script>
}
```

Is this good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would go with an extension of the 2nd option and create a seperate .js file. The reason being, if you delegate work out to a 3rd party to take care of the jquery/javascript parts of the UI, then they need not have any sight of the backend functionality.

There are a variety of ways to use html5 attributes (i.e. data-attribute='foo') on the inputs which would allow you to 'decorate' your inputs with a cargo of properties which could be parsed inside the external .js file.

A very brief example:

in your view:

```
<input type='text' id='myId' data-action='@Url.Action("MyAction")' class='myClass' />
```

in your .js file:

```
var targetAction = $('#myId').attr('data-action');
```

this gives complete separation between the .js and the views. It does require a degree of planning of course.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Razor will be parsed at server-side and replaced by relevant output. Therefore, in my opinion it is totally indifferent, if you place it in Javascript or HTML - at client side only the output value will be visible. Thus, in the above example I would choose the first option (place it directly in JS), since you will not have the otherwise unnecessary hidden input field.

Comment: I'm worrying about clean code. For example if I want to place javascript in separate .js files?

Comment: Then, of course it won't work like that and you will have to utilize hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a correct answer to this question; only pros and cons.

*Pros of using Razor in Javascript*

- Script is bound to your view model; so model changes will get picked up automatically, and errors will get caught at compile time.

*Cons*

- Script is mixed with markup, contrary to web design best practices (put script at the bottom so that it will never break your page).
- Script cannot be compiled/minified, because, again, it's mixed in with your markup.

Comment: And which way you suggest me? how do you think, which way is better in your opinion

Comment: @karaxuna well, I tend to agree with Trogvar's points; *unless* you are building sites for mobile devices and are working with a large amount of script.

Comment: @karaxuna then I'd probably lean towards using external .JS files.  I see that jim tollan raises some more good points that could be added to my *pros* list above.

Comment: thanks @dbaseman. Now I thought about different solution. please take a look at edit